# Class "model.Address" is listed in the persistence.xml file but not mapped

Tags: eclipse, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have created a `JPA` project. In that Eclipse displays the following error on the entity class.

> Class "model.Address" is listed in the `persistence.xml` file but not mapped

How am I supposed to map the entity class in `persistance.xml`?

Here is the `model.Address` entity:

```java
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String province;
    private String postalCode;
    private String street;

    // Getters/setters omitted for brevity.
}
```

Here is the `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" 
>
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistance.example.jpa.20.employee.annotations</provider>

    <persistence-unit name="employee" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>model.Employee</class>
        <class>model.Address</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="scott" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="tiger" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: first - by showing us your mapping files. Honestly - how do you think we can "debug" a problem if we know nothing but an error message.

Comment: ok, formulating the question is a good thing, but I'd still like to see your `persistence.xml`

Answer (score 124):

This is an Eclipse quirk. I recently had exactly this problem when I created a new JPA project with the JPA library configuration disabled, but didn't manually configure the JPA libraries *before* I created the entities by the Eclipse *New JPA Entity* wizard. After creating the entities I configured the JPA libraries in project's *Build Path* (just by adding target Java EE server runtime in *Libraries*), but the validation error still remains. I could solve it in at least one of following ways:

1. Rightclick `persistence.xml` file, *JPA Tools* -> *Synchronize Class List*.
2. Or, rightclick project, *Validate*.
3. Or, close/reopen project.

This is consistently reproducible. I was using Eclipse Indigo SR1. When I create the entities *after* configuring the JPA libraries, this validation error doesn't occur.

Comment: Wow, strange issue. After using _JPA Tools -> Synchronize Class List_ the related classes inside the `<persistence-unit>` block were removed. And although those validation errors are gone, I wonder if that's OK...

Comment: thank you so much for your  kind information @BalusC

Comment: I confirm @BalusC statement - This is consistently reproducible, reproduced and applied solution in 2019, works perfect! ▲

Comment: rightclick project, Validate - seems simplest. It worked for me

Comment: @BalusC is a god!

Comment: That's solve the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Right click on jpa project

then

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think you have the wrong JPA provider class. It has to be:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

(the one you've set doesn't seem to be a class at all, let alone a provider class)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your class is annotated with [@Entity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html)
(from javax.persistence.Entity)

I realise that's not the OP's problem, but I got caught by that and Google sent me here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a persistence file and a ORM mapping file for JPA, refer the mapping file from persistence file.

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/hbase-orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>com.xxx.logcollector.entity.DefaultLogableEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.jpa.addClassTransformer" value="false" />
        <property name="datanucleus.managedRuntime" value="false" />
```

....

Create ORM mapping file

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <entity class="com.xxx.cne.logcollector.entity.DefaultLogableEntity"
        name="DefaultLogableEntity">
        <table name="RAW_LOG_COLLECTION" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="clientHostIP">
                <column name="ANALYTICS:CLIENT_IP" />
            </id>
            <basic name="requestDateTime">
                <column name="ANALYTICS:REQUEST_DATETIME" />
            </basic>
```

...

Create entity manager in spring

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"></property>
```

Answer (score 3):

If eclipse is used , go to `Window>Preference>Validation` and uncheck `Suspend all validators` option .Clean the project and problem get solved.

Comment: you might not get your answer accepted as this question was very old.

Answer (score 3):

Any of the above didnt work.

For anyone who is searching for the "Class xxxx is mapped, but is not included in any persistence unit" error in Eclipse or RAD:

1. Right-click on the project and choose properties.
2. Select JPA
3. Select the radio button "Discover annotated classes automatically"
4. OK and wait for the project to finish building.

These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It should be written like:

```
@Entity
**@Table(name="Address",schema="ABCD")** `
```

...or it could be written like :

```
@Entity
public class Address {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

i got similar error and when  eclipse artifacts folder ".settings" is missed .
After i generate eclipse artifacts using "maven-eclipse-plugin" , the error is gone