# Class is managed, but is not listed in the persistence.xml file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I am getting the following exception in my project:

> Class "com.testApp.domain.Register" is managed, but is not listed in the persistence.xml file

My `persistence.xml` file looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.detection" value="class, hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:." />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="SA" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I have tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242637/class-model-address-is-listed-in-the-persistence-xml-file-but-not-mapped) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051055/must-every-entity-bean-be-registered-in-persistence-xml), both suggest to add the class manually or automatically to the `persistence.xml`. Others say its a eclipse related issue and can be solved by cleaning or reopening of the project. However, I want that these classes get autodetected by hibernate and not manually add them to my `persistence.xml`.

Any suggestions for a solution and to solve my error?

I appreciate your reply!

UPDATE

My `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.testApp" annotation-config="true" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Spring you could avoid `persistence.xml` file and declare instead an entity manager factory like this:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="yourDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.testApp.domain" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

All the entities in `com.testApp.domain` package (marked with `@Entity` annotation) will be loaded without declaring them in XML.

**UPDATE** You need to declarate a data source, for example:

```
<bean id="yourDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:." />
    <property name="username" value="SA" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
</bean>
```

Then you can use the `entityManager` exactly as you were doing. I suppose you are using something similar in your DAO classes:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! I have added in an UPDATE my `applicationContext.xml`. In your case which properties are still needed for the `entitiyManagerFactory`? Furthermore, I would have to call this in my DAO methods, right? What are the advantages with this approach? I appreciate your answer!

Comment: You only need to declare a data source with your DB parameters (I updated my answer).

Comment: Thx for your answer! What would be the data source for a `hsqldb`?

Comment: just replace expressions with your parameters... DONE.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 59):

If you are using Eclipse:(1) Select: (Your Project) -> Properties -> JPA;
(2) Look for "Persistent class management" and select the option "Discover annotated classes automatically";
(3) Press "Apply".

Comment: That approach is specific to an IDE, however.

Comment: it works for me (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers 4.4.2)

Comment: It work well, It just apper after update my google app engine project from kepler to mars.

Comment: Works for me with Rational Application Developer for Websphere 8.5.5.7  (IBM Eclipse). Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If it is an Eclipse problem, go to:

```
Preferences >> Java Persistence >> JPA >> Errors/Warnings >> Type
```

in the following itens, mark then as `Ignore`:

- Class is annotated, but is not listed in the persistence.xml file
- Class is managed, but is not listed in the persistence.xml file

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me with Eclipse 2019-06, but it is not a general preference so I had to enabled project-specific preferences for JPA first and set it there.

Comment: For Eclipse 2020-09, right click on the project -> properties->JPA, select option 'Discover Annotated Classes Automatically".